# System.TypeInitializationException: "Инициализатор типа для Program вызвал исключение."

Tags: c#, файлы

System.TypeInitializationException: "The type initializer for 'Program' threw an exception."
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Db

Неделю назад у меня всё работало нормально, но сейчас - выдаёт ошибку, я пробую создать недостающие папки для будущей работы с ними.
При выдаче ошибки ни одна из папок так и не была создана

Код:

```
string toFilePath = "C:\\World\\";
new List<string> {"", "region", "DIM1", "DIM-1", "DIM1\\region", "DIM-1\\region" }.ForEach(x => Directory.CreateDirectory(toFilePath + x));
```

Comment: "При выдаче ошибки" - какой ошибки?

Comment: @Igor, первые две строки - "ошибка"

Comment: Ошибка за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: Неправильно директории делаете, измените код на `.ForEach(x => Directory.CreateDirectory(toFilePath 
 + "\\" + x);`, скорее всего исключение из-за этого, т.к не может найти папки которые вам нужны из-за ошибочного создания самих папок.

Comment: Автору бы познакомиться с буквальным строковым литералом `@"..."` и `Path.Combine()`. Несмотря на это, я запустил ваш код, работает.

Comment: @aepot, я использую @, но только в случаях когда: нужно использовать красиво абзацы без \n, у меня хотя бы более 4 '\'

Answer (score 0):

Да, VS22 показывала неправильную строку, как ошибку.
Проблема была в словаре, находившемся за методом Main, я перепутал в словаре Key и Value, пример моей ошибки:

```
Dictionary<string, byte> blocks = new Dictionary<string, byte>() {"Bd", 32}, {"Bd", 31}};
```